# How to set Target Application in Windows Performance Recorder for measuring Heap Usage

Tags: performance, memory, wpa

All the tutorials for using Heap Usage provider in Windows Performance Recorder require you to set Target Application in the WPR GUI.

Unfortunately in the most recent version of WPR there is no combo box that allows you to to this.
Does anyone know how to create a Heap Usage trace for a given process using WPR?

Here is a comparison of the old UI and the new one:
[image]

Someone already [asked this question on Microsoft forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7cd2d4fd-55f1-47f3-94e6-64cc8c4a04cb/windows-performance-recorder-target-application-option-doesnt-show-up), but there was no solution.